# Google Sheets Script to move completed rows to new sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which moves data from one sheet to another when data is added to column "I".

I'd like to adapt the script to perform the action of moving all rows (values) from the 'unpaid' sheet, where column I is not empty, to the paid sheet via a button press rather than 'on edit'. This will allow moving of data from multiple rows at once, rather than with the current script which only moves one row at a time.

Please can someone assist?

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();


  if(s.getName() == "Unpaid" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() != "") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = 11;
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paid");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo((target),{contentsOnly:true});
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } 
  else if(s.getName() == "Paid" && r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Unpaid");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Side note, the "else if" part of the script is designed to move the code back to the original sheet. This isn't needed but I wasn't able to delete that part of the code and maintain functionality.

Comment: I see, i guess it's both of those things. 1) i'd like to transfer all rows (range = the same columns as in above code) where column I is not empty and 2) use a button to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The first step is to find the rows in the `Unpaid` sheet for which column **I** is **not** empty. To achieve that, you can apply a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:%7E:text=The%20conditional%20(ternary)%20operator%20is,if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy.) operator to every element of column **I**. In more detail, you can use the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to check whether the element is empty or not and then apply a [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select only the rows with a non empty value in column **I**:

  ```
  const movRows =  iVals.map((c,i)=>c!=''?i:null).filter(f=>f!=null);
  ```
- `movRows` contains the indexes for which column **I** is **not** empty. To get the actual row, you need to add **2** to the elements of `movRows` since we started from the second row `I2:I`.
- The next step is to iterate over the `movRows` array and for every element, delete the row in the `Unpaid` sheet and move it to `Paid` sheet. We are not moving it directly, but instead pushing the data to the `movData` array and then use this array to transfer this data for efficiency purposes.
- The iteration needs to happen **backwards** otherwise every time you delete a row there will be a **mismatch** between the actual data and the structure of the sheet.
- To create a button in the *UI*, you can use an [onOpen()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) trigger. The only thing you need to do, is to **save** the following script to the script editor and then a custom menu button will appear in the UI (spreadsheet). You can click that button to execute the `transfer()` function.

---

### Solution:

```
function transfer() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const pSh = ss.getSheetByName('Paid');
const upSh = ss.getSheetByName('Unpaid');
const numColumns = 11;
const iVals = upSh.getRange('I2:I'+upSh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();  
const movData = [];
const movRows =  iVals.map((c,i)=>c!=''?i:null).filter(f=>f!=null);
movRows.reverse().forEach(row=>{ 
    movData.push(upSh.getRange(row+2,1,1,numColumns).getValues()[0]);
    upSh.deleteRow(row+2);                                    
  });   
pSh.getRange(pSh.getLastRow()+1,1,movData.length,movData[0].length).setValues(movData);   
}
```

and the **custom menu button** is created by using an `onOpen` trigger:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Macros')
  .addItem('Transfer Rows', 'transfer')
  .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, this is great

Comment: @user13599639 I added a lot more to the answer. Explanation & how you can create a custom menu button.